# Spark Scala : Add Case class object to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a simple empty dataframe created as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

lazy val sess = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
case class MyClass (id:String, name:String)
val resultDf = sess.emptyDataset[MyClass]
```

now, i just want to create a new object, and append it to the dataframe. How do I do that? I have tried many things but failed

```
val x = MyClass("123", "zxc")
resultDf.union(x)

<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ValidSignals
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ValidSignals]
       resultDf.union(x)
```

How can I convert the object to something that can be appended to the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union` expects a `Dataset[_]` as an argument. You need

```
val emptyDS = sess.emptyDataset[MyClass] 
val resultDS = emptyDS.union(Seq(MyClass("123","abc")).toDS())
resultDS.collect() // Array(MyClass(123,abc))
```